# Conversion of NSDate to NSString giving different output

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

This could be repeated one but I am not able to find the correct solution.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd"];
 NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:receiveddate];
 NSLog(@"Date: %@", dateString);
```

receiveddate is NSDate and its value is **2012-06-11 00:00:00 +0000**
I just want to convert the above date into NSString where value should be just **2012-06-11**

But when I checked it out it gives me different output that is **2012-00-11 00:00:00**. It's strange. How can I get out from this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I  am using the same code what you have posted and it's giving me the right output what You want. So i think the problem with the format of your receiveddate. Here is tha code what i m using

```
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] ;
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd"];
    NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
    NSLog(@"Date: %@", dateString);

OUTPUT:Date: 2012-06-06
```

Comment: That's fine. But how do I convert 2012-06-11 00:00:00 +0000 date into 2012-06-11 or How do I remove formatting of my existing date.

Comment: NSString *s = @"2012-06-11 00:00:00 +0000";
    NSRange range = NSMakeRange (0, 10); 
   NSLog(@"%@ ", [s substringWithRange:range]);OUTPUT:2012-06-11

Comment: Fine I am getting output 2012-06-11 correctly. Now how do I extract only date 11 from this string.

Comment: NSCalendar *cal = [[NSCalendar alloc] init];
NSDateComponents *components = [cal components:0 fromDate:date];
int year = [components year];
int month = [components month];
int day = [components day];

Answer (score 5):

You Can Use This :

`[formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];`

`[formatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];`

`[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];`

Comment: it may be because in Date formate "yyyy" should be in small case.while testing in device.

Comment: Now you  are  saying right and no  need to  set dateStyle..thanks for sharing your knowledge..:)

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd"];
dateFormat.dateStyle = kCFDateFormatterShortStyle;
```

Comment: That's fine. But how do I convert 2012-06-11 00:00:00 +0000 date into 2012-06-11 or How do I remove formatting of my existing date

Comment: this will give you short formate of your date, that is just date, not the time. is that not removed still?

Comment: Its giving me output 6/11/12 even the specified format is @"YYYY-MM-dd".

Comment: ok. change arrangements of above lines. that is dateFormat.dateStyle = kCFDateFormatterShortStyle; and then [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd"];

Answer (score 0):

The problem I find out is **2012-06-11 00:00:00 +0000** is not a valid NSDate.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is that you are using `YYYY`  instead of  `yyyy`   ?

Atleast I'm using it like this:   `[mDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-M-dd"];` to get `2012-6-5`.